# Trace of $3 \times 3$ matrix A and the polynomial $p(z)=det(z\cdot I_{3} - A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant

> Consider $A \in \mathcal{M}^{3{\times}3}(\mathbb{C}) $ where
>   $$ A = 
> \left[
> \begin{matrix}
> a_{1 1} & a_{12}& a_{13}\\
> a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
> a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
> \end{matrix}
> \right]
> $$
>
> - Show that $p(z)= \det(z\cdot I_{3} - A)$ is a third degree monic  polynomial.
> - If $p(z)= (z- c_{1})(z-c_{2})(z-c_{3})$ where $c_{j} \in \mathbb{C}$, then:
>     $$
>   \operatorname{trace}(A) = c_{1} + c_{2} + c_{3},\quad
>   \text{and}\quad \det(A)=c_{1}\cdot c_{2} \cdot c_{3}
>   $$

The first part is just calculating the determinant, so I've done it.

To prove that $\det(A)=c_{1}\cdot c_{2} \cdot c_{3}$ I have to just plug in $z=0$ in the first part and computing $\det(-A)$. I see that 
$$
\det(-A)= -\det(A)$$ which is exactly what I need, because 
$$
p(0)=-c_{1}\cdot c_{2} \cdot c_{3},$$ 
hence 
$$
-\det(A)= -c_{1}\cdot c_{2} \cdot c_{3}.
$$

I'm having trouble proving that 
$$\operatorname{trace}(A) = c_{1} + c_{2} + c_{3}.$$

So can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: The title is because, first I searched for any relationship between a matrix and it's trace, and I found it has something to do with eigenvalues, but that is a topic I haven't seen in my course of algebra, so I don't know how to find them or what are they.

Comment: The $c_j$'s are by definition eigenvalues of $A$. I would write something like "The trace of a $3\times 3$ matrix and the polynomial $p(z)=\det(zI_3-A)$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write out explicitly $b_0,b_2,b_3$ in 
$$
p(z):=\det(zI_3-A)
=b_3z^3+b_2z^2+b_1z+b_0
$$
then part II simply follows from [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas). In your post, you have actually figured out what are $b_0$ and $b_3$. All you need now is finding out $b_2$ which can be done by observation of the [determinant of the $3\times 3$ matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#3_%C3%97_3_matrices).